# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'

Tags: python

```
 def leer_archivo(archivo):
        linea = archivo.readline()
        linea = linea.rstrip('\n')
        if not linea:
            linea = MAXIMO + ',0'
        return linea.split(',')


    def grabar_nuevo(archivo,fecha, sucursal, monto):
        archivo.write(fecha +',' + sucursal+','+ monto+ '\n')

    def grabar_error(archivo, fecha, sucursal, monto):
        archivo.write(fecha + ',' + sucursal+','+ monto +'\n')

    def mezclar_archivo(sucursal_1, sucursal_2, sucursal_general, errores):
        fecha_s1, sucursal_1,monto1 = leer_archivo(sucursal_1)
        fecha_s2, sucursal_2, monto2 = leer_archivo(sucursal_2)

        while ( fecha_s1 != MAXIMO or fecha_s2 != MAXIMO ):
                min_fecha = min(fecha_s1, fecha_s2)

                while (fecha_s1 == min_fecha):
                    grabar_nuevo(sucursal_general, fecha_s1, sucursal_1, monto1)
                    fecha_1, sucursal_1, monto1 = leer_archivo(sucursal_1)

                while (fecha_s2 == min_fecha):
                    grabar_nuevo(sucursal_general, fecha_s2, sucursal_2, monto2)
                    fecha_s2, sucursal_2, monto2 = leer_archivo(sucursal_2)

    MAXIMO = "99999"
sucursal_1 = open("sucursal_1.txt","r")
sucursal_2 = open ("sucursal_2.txt","r")
sucursal_general = open("sucursal_general.txt","w")
errores = open ("errores.txt","w")

mezclar_archivo(sucursal_1, sucursal_2, sucursal_general, errores)

sucursal_1.close()
sucursal_2.close()
sucursal_general.close()
errores.close()
```

Tengo dos archivos para leer, son varias lineas de este tipo
 2020-02-01, sucursal1, 50000
ordenado por fecha de menor a mayor ambos archivos.
y en el segundo archivo  puede tener los mismos campos o (menos o mas) y esa linea la tengo que mandar al archivo de error.
Como hago esto? y como soluciono el error que me da en 
linea = archivo.readline()

Answer (score 1):

El error te da en la función `def leer_archivo(archivo):` porque estas pasando una cadena de caracteres y no un puntero al archivo.

Antes de esta linea

```py
linea = archivo.readline()
```

Deberias agregar el puntero que manejara el archivo

```py
file= open(archivo, "r", encoding="utf-8")
linea = file.readline()
```